# Query Redshift from Hive not pushing down predicates

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I launched an AWS EMR cluster with EMR 5.28.0, Spark and Hive.
I was used to Spark SQL with spark-redshift connector that made me able to read/write in Redshift creating external tables like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`redshift_table` (`id` INT, `object_id` STRING)
USING com.databricks.spark.redshift
OPTIONS (
  `tempdir` 's3a://my_bucket/table/',
  `url` 'jdbc:redshift://xxxxxx:5439/database?user=user&password=password',
  `forward_spark_s3_credentials` 'true',
  `serialization.format` '1',
  `dbtable` 'my.table'
)
```

Now I am looking for the equivalent thing in Hive:

- at least to be able to read a Redshift table from Hive (so I can join Redshift data with other tables from the datalake)
- and if possible to write to Redshift from Hive too (so I can create ETLs in the data lake writing some results to Redshift)

I've been looking around but I'm not sure what would be the format of the CREATE TABLE and if I need to install something else on the cluster before.

Thanks

**Update**:
I have been able to do it with EMR 5.28.0 now using those jars:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc-handler/3.1.2
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.37.1061/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.37.1061.jar

and then creating the table in Hive with:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.table(
    id INTEGER,
    name STRING
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "hive.sql.database.type" = "POSTGRES",
    "hive.sql.jdbc.driver" = "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver",
    "hive.sql.jdbc.url" = "jdbc:redshift://host:5439/database",
    "hive.sql.dbcp.username" = "user",
    "hive.sql.dbcp.password" = "password",
    "hive.sql.table" = "schema.name",
    "hive.sql.dbcp.maxActive" = "1"
);
```

The issue I have now is that it does not push down predicates to Redshift. For example "SELECT * FROM test.table where id = 1;" first executes a Redshift query reading the whole table, any idea how to change this behavior please?

I checked the Hive settings and I have:

```
hive.optimize.ppd=true
hive.optimize.ppd.storage=true
```

Comment: is there any reason to move away from using the spark-redshift connector? I would still prefer to use JDBC connection to read from redshift in spark, its more cleaner. Also, I have not tried this but you could create an external table in glue-catalog pointing to your respective table in redshift and set the glue catalog as metastore in your EMR's hive. This should allow you to read the data from redshift into spark.

Comment: The reason is because the spark-redshift connector is not updated by Databricks anymore since 2016 (at least the open-source version) so it will stop working at some point with new releases of Spark or Redshift.
And in Glue Catalog I'm not able to point to a Redshift table unfortunately. I will see if with the new federated queries tools for Athena it's possible to do so.

Comment: I guess you can also connect to redshift using the psycopg2 python lib as well as it postgre only behind the scene.

Comment: I would like to be able to do everything in SQL so that analysts can do all their stuff (Redshift to Hive, Hive to Redshift, joins between Hive and Redshift, etc...) with a SQL client using Spark Thrift Server or HiveServer.

Comment: In the end I managed to use spark-redshift connector again with Glue Data Catalog as the metastore. The issue I had was because I had to use a database with a non-empty location to make my DDL work in Spark SQL (basically putting a random value for the 'location' field for the database I use in Glue Data Catalog UI solved it). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

Comment: That's great. About your updated question, the column you are trying to apply a filter on, is it a partition column. I think spark only uses pushdown for partition columns.

Comment: It's a Redshift table and I don't think there is a concept of partitions for Redshift tables (except for Redshift Spectrum reading from S3)

Comment: The latest version of Hive should support pushdown: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JdbcStorageHandler My guess is that EMR has an older version of Hive. EMR 5.28.0 has Hive 2.3.6(https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/JdbcStorageHandler)  while Apache Hive community has release 3.1.2 (https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html)